# wireshark - failed to get the current screen resources

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, wireshark

I am using ssh with(-X) `ssh -X 192.168.1.128` to connect the ubuntu server (16.04.1 LTS), when I try use wireshark with this command: `controller@controller:~$ wireshark`.

**It return next error:**

```
failed to get the current screen resources
The X11 connection broke: I/O error (code 1)
XIO:  fatal IO error 2 (No such file or directory) on X server "localhost:10.0"
      after 349 requests (349 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
controller@controller:~$
```

Can yo help me to solve this problem?

Thanks for you attention,
Carlos Silva

**To install wireshark I use next commands:**

```
sudo apt-get install -y software-properties-common python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pi-rho/security 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wireshark
```

Comment: I have exactly the same issue with wireshark 2.2.6+g32dac6a-2ubuntu0.16.04 over remote desktop (x2go)

Answer (score 1):

You could install wireshark-gtk and use it instead of wireshark:

```
ubuntu@mrouter02:~$ sudo apt install wireshark-gtk
...
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Setting up wireshark-gtk (2.2.6+g32dac6a-2ubuntu0.16.04)
...

ubuntu@mrouter02:~$ wireshark /tmp/dbus.pcap 

failed to get the current screen resources
The X11 connection broke: I/O error (code 1)
XIO:  fatal IO error 2 (No such file or directory) on X server "localhost:11.0"
  after 349 requests (349 known processed) with 0 events remaining.

ubuntu@mrouter02:~$ wireshark-gtk /tmp/dbus.pcap 

** (wireshark-gtk:8621): WARNING **: Couldn't register with accessibility     
bus: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, 
the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the  reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.

ubuntu@mrouter02:~$
```

Warnings are not affecting wireshark-gtk usability.

Answer (score 0):

I had a

```
Gdk-Message: 11:11:10.047: wireshark: Fatal IO error 2 (No such file or directory) on X server :55
```

I was using Xvnc on port 5955. I discovered the problem to be a leftover LD_LIBRARY_PATH set in the bash session I was calling wireshark from. I just needed to remove it and wireshark ran fine.